# I want to check my rules with Validator, but the validator is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

> I have a few rules for validator e-mail and password of my registration page and I want to check them. But it's not working.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class register extends StatefulWidget {
  register({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _registerState createState() => _registerState();
}

class _registerState extends State<register> {
  late TextEditingController textController1;
  late TextEditingController textController2;
  late bool passwordVisibility1;
  late TextEditingController textController3;
  late bool passwordVisibility2;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String error = '';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textController1 = TextEditingController();
    textController2 = TextEditingController();
    passwordVisibility1 = false;
    textController3 = TextEditingController();
    passwordVisibility2 = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: Image.asset(
                    'assets/img/backgraund_page.jpg',
                  ).image,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, -0.8),
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/logo/Aet_page-0001-removebg-preview.png',
                width: 250,
                height: 170,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 300, 0, 0),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 565,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(0),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 70, 0, 0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                        ),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) =>
                              val!.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              email = val;
                            });
                          },
                          controller: textController1,
                          obscureText: false,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'E-Posta',
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0x00000000),
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0x00000000),
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 120, 0, 0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                        ),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) => val!.length < 6
                              ? 'Ender a password 6+ chars long'
                              : null,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              password = val;
                            });
                          },
                          controller: textController2,
                          obscureText: !passwordVisibility1,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Password',
                            enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0x00000000),
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0x00000000),
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            suffixIcon: InkWell(
                              onTap: () => setState(
                                () =>
                                    passwordVisibility1 = !passwordVisibility1,
                              ),
                              child: Icon(
                                passwordVisibility1
                                    ? Icons.visibility_outlined
                                    : Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
                                color: Color(0xFF757575),
                                size: 22,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 170, 0, 0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                        height: 50,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                        ),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: textController3,
                          obscureText: !passwordVisibility2,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                            enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0x00000000),
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0x00000000),
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            suffixIcon: InkWell(
                              onTap: () => setState(
                                () =>
                                    passwordVisibility2 = !passwordVisibility2,
                              ),
                              child: Icon(
                                passwordVisibility2
                                    ? Icons.visibility_outlined
                                    : Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
                                color: Color(0xFF757575),
                                size: 22,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 120, 0, 0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                        height: 1,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Color(0xFFB9B7B7),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 170, 0, 0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                        height: 1,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Color(0xFFB9B7B7),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 220, 0, 0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                        height: 1,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Color(0xFFB9B7B7),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 270, 0, 0),
                      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 40,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print(email);
                            print(password);
                          },
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          color: Color(0xFF36A8D3),
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Sign In",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(65, 512, 0, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Are you already a member?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(265, 512, 0, 0),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () async {
                          await Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => loginpage(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Login In',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> hello everyone, above are the codes for my registration page. With Validator I have a few rules required for e-mail password and I want to check these rules, but the validator is not working at all. How can I fix this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your `TextFormField` with `Form`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class register extends StatefulWidget {
  register({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _registerState createState() => _registerState();
}

class _registerState extends State<register> {
  late TextEditingController textController1;
  late TextEditingController textController2;
  late bool passwordVisibility1;
  late TextEditingController textController3;
  late bool passwordVisibility2;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String error = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textController1 = TextEditingController();
    textController2 = TextEditingController();
    passwordVisibility1 = false;
    textController3 = TextEditingController();
    passwordVisibility2 = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  image: Image.asset(
                    'assets/img/backgraund_page.jpg',
                  ).image,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, -0.8),
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/logo/Aet_page-0001-removebg-preview.png',
                width: 250,
                height: 170,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 300, 0, 0),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 565,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(0),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Form(
                  key: formKey,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 70, 0, 0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                          height: 50,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                          ),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            validator: (val) =>
                                val!.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() {
                                email = val;
                              });
                            },
                            controller: textController1,
                            obscureText: false,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'E-Posta',
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color(0x00000000),
                                  width: 1,
                                ),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color(0x00000000),
                                  width: 1,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 120, 0, 0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                          height: 50,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                          ),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            validator: (val) => val!.length < 6
                                ? 'Ender a password 6+ chars long'
                                : null,
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() {
                                password = val;
                              });
                            },
                            controller: textController2,
                            obscureText: !passwordVisibility1,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Password',
                              enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color(0x00000000),
                                  width: 1,
                                ),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color(0x00000000),
                                  width: 1,
                                ),
                              ),
                              suffixIcon: InkWell(
                                onTap: () => setState(
                                  () =>
                                      passwordVisibility1 = !passwordVisibility1,
                                ),
                                child: Icon(
                                  passwordVisibility1
                                      ? Icons.visibility_outlined
                                      : Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
                                  color: Color(0xFF757575),
                                  size: 22,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 170, 0, 0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                          height: 50,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                          ),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: textController3,
                            obscureText: !passwordVisibility2,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                              enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color(0x00000000),
                                  width: 1,
                                ),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color(0x00000000),
                                  width: 1,
                                ),
                              ),
                              suffixIcon: InkWell(
                                onTap: () => setState(
                                  () =>
                                      passwordVisibility2 = !passwordVisibility2,
                                ),
                                child: Icon(
                                  passwordVisibility2
                                      ? Icons.visibility_outlined
                                      : Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
                                  color: Color(0xFF757575),
                                  size: 22,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 120, 0, 0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                          height: 1,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Color(0xFFB9B7B7),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 170, 0, 0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                          height: 1,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Color(0xFFB9B7B7),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 220, 0, 0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                          height: 1,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Color(0xFFB9B7B7),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(40, 270, 0, 0),
                        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 40,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if(!formKey.currentState!.validate()) return;
                              
                              print(email);
                              print(password);
                            },
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            color: Color(0xFF36A8D3),
                            child: const Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Sign In",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(65, 512, 0, 0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Are you already a member?',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(265, 512, 0, 0),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () async {
                            await Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => loginpage(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            'Login In',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontSize: 15,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```